# how do i send data from webhook to frontend?

Tags: websocket, webhooks

I have an API that continuously sends data to a webhook in my express server. The route in my server looks something like this:

```
app.post("/webhook", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).end();
});
```

How do I send data to my frontend as they're coming in? Is it possible to place a websocket between my frontend and backend? If so, can anyone please point to a tutorial? Much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use socket.io to enable a bidirectional comunication between your frontend and backend.

Each time the third party API sends data throught your webhook, you could trigger a socket event and receive a realtime update in your front end.

check: https://socket.io
It's simple and have a good documentation.

Comment: thanks for confirming it can be done -- i'll take a look.